# VirtualBox Windows 10 64 Bit Host - The VM session was aborted

Tags: virtualbox

I'm trying to make a Win 7 64 bit guest machine. When it's time to load the ISO, I try to load it and I get the following error

```
The VM session was aborted.
Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: SessionMachine
Interface: ISession {7844aa05-b02e-4cdd-a04f-ade4a762e6b7}
```

What's a fix for this? Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have the same issue, and hopefully there will be a bug-fix for it soon.

In the meantime, I have managed to start the install process (in my case for Linux mint 17.2 rather than windows) by attaching the .iso image in the VirtualBox IDE Storage Settings page rather than the "mount" dialog that causes the error.

Open the settings for your VM in the VirtualBox UI, go to Storage, click on the "empty" entry in the list of IDE Controllers, and select the disk icon over to the right of the screen.  Finally, select to "Choose Virtual Optical Disk File", and select your .iso of choice.  Then start the VM and it should boot just fine.

I hope it helps for your case too!

Answer (score 4):

update the extension pack was my solution

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it will help.
I turned off sound card , and at virtual machine I had "audio" controller turned on.
When I turned off audio controler virtual machine start normaly.

BR  Simon

Comment: Can confirm this worked for me. I just changed to the Null Audio Driver.

Comment: this has just happened to me too... I can confirm disabling audio works, but in my case I need audio to be on... Is there any actual fix?

Answer (score 2):

1. Backed up the last saved snapshot from C:\Users\\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu\Snapshots
2. Go to Machine> Ignore last saved state.

Restart VM.

This worked.

This issue most likely happened for me because my Windows 10 randomly restarted a couple of time, with BSOD.

Error code

```
Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: SessionMachine
Interface: ISession {7844aa05-b02e-4cdd-a04f-ade4a762e6b7}
```

Comment: I did step 2 directly and it worked for me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Menu -> Machine -> Discard Saved State...

This worked.

Answer (score 0):

Menu -> Machine -> Reset all warnings

worked for me

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the same error. 

Is this your error code? 
Result Code: 
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: 
SessionMachine
Interface: 
ISession {7844aa05-b02e-4cdd-a04f-ade4a762e6b7}

Answer (score 0):

1. start your virtual machine
2. start ubuntu
3. open settings in ubuntu and go to display
4. set resolution to 16:9
   and you are done

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me in the weirdest of circumstances, it just stopped working out of nowhere on Windows. To check if you have the same problem as me go to "Settings" and then "Shared Folders", try to create new shared folders and deleting them. When you click OK if you get an an error message saying you don't have permission or can't access, then it's user permission issue, go to where the virtual machine is on your file system and make "read", "modify" and "write", hell just select "all" on that folder, or probably better yet the entire Folder containing the application.